# Audio EQ Cookbook without frequency warping

Tags: filter-design

The famous https://www.w3.org/TR/audio-eq-cookbook/ offers a set of [real] biquad filter calculation formulas that generally work fine.

However, when filter's frequency approaches Nyquist frequency the Q (bandwidth) specification of a filter becomes greatly distorted - usually it shrinks a lot (even though the author mentioned that he performed a necessary pre-warping).

I'm in quest for filter formulas that do not have such strong bandwidth distortion. I need peaking/bell, band-pass, low-pass, high-pass, high-shelf, notch filters. I know this can be done as previously I've bought a peaking/bell/band-pass filter formulas with less distortion, but they are still not perfect and I need other filter types.

So, I'm also willing to pay for the solution if the price is right.

Alternatively, if one could point me to an optimization algorithm that works with Z-domain filters that would be great, too. Unfortunately, most usual optimization algorithms do not work well in Z-domain - they can't optimize a set of parameters to match a desired frequency response (probably due to periodic functions used to calculate the frequency response).

Comment: Would FIR filters also do the job for you? Just asking because they're much easier to design, especially for more complicated specs.

Comment: Sorry, FIR filters are not suitable in this case.

Comment: Complexity or delay?

Comment: They are not suitable due to delay, in real-time use. They are also too computationally-intensive.

Comment: In order to effectively compensate the aliasing and warping artefacts for discrete filters you have to use very high orders. FIR would make the design much easier indeed, but there are also other methods. In order to give you a meaningful answer I would like to know what exactly your computational constraints are (including platform), and what your processing requirements are. Why do you need this behaviour, and would oversampling not suffice?

Comment: This is to be used in music sequencer software, on many sound tracks at once. So, FIR and oversampling are not an option. High order IIR filters are not needed: as I've already noted, this is doable in biquad form, but needs complex math, that's the catch. The resulting response does not have to be an exact match to analog prototype at all frequencies, but should keep the bandwidth.

Comment: well, there's a limit to what you can get with a 2nd-order IIR filter.  there is [another paper by Orfanidis that puts the gain at Nyquist to be something other than 0 dB](http://www.ece.rutgers.edu/~orfanidi/ece521/peq.pdf) (the Cookbook puts the Nyquist gain at 0 dB because that's how the bilinear transform maps it).  for a 44.1 kHz sample rate, and 2nd-order biquad, i don't think you'll do much better than the Orfanidis design.

Comment: The best method I'm aware of is not directly mapping to the discrete domain but rather applying ODE solvers to the analog prototype. Specifically implicit solvers do a great job at preserving the frequency response.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac: Why use an analog prototype instead of designing directly in the discrete-time domain?

Comment: @MattL.The analog prototype has desirable properties like scale invariance which makes the design of constant-Q filters specifically easy. But the real reason is that it avoids the artefacts introduced by a finite sampling rate like response aliasing and all kinds of response distortion. So you can design exactly what you want and using a ODE solver does not(!) necessarily map it to what we call z-domain. Higher order and/or implicit solvers map to a more general set of (recursive) discrete models and sometimes even violate strict linearity while still describing a linear analog system.

Comment: what order filter are you typing about, @Jazzmaniac?  2nd-order biquad, 5 coefficients, [5 degrees of freedom](https://www.zotero.org/jdigerness/items/itemKey/HHUSGAR2).  can't do much more with it.

Comment: robert bristow-johnson, first of all, thanks for the cookbook. To my knowledge, Orfanidis design is glitchy - it has some weird discontinuities at some frequencies. The design I've purchased is much better than that, so it's doable. I would try to ask for more filter designs from the same designer, but they left the field of DSP.

Comment: Jazzmaniac, I'm not much familiar with ODE solvers, but I've used ordinary least squares linear equations solver (via LU decomposition). But I do not think it can solve complex-numbered linear equations, or am I mistaken on this?

Comment: Also, the constraint to the equation solver is that resulting X'es have to be real, not complex numbers, so this complicates things a lot.

Comment: @aleksv: You could post a concrete design problem with all specs and see what we come up with.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, I'm not talking about biquads or any order of filters here. ODE solvers do not generally map to recursive linear difference equations. Take a 2nd order linear ODE as an analog prototype for example and run a trapezoidal fixed time step solver on it. The result is not a recursive filter but something involving a division for every time step. It cannot be described by a fixed order recursive filter of finite complexity in general.

Comment: @matt-l, sorry I do not know how to formulate it better than that.

Comment: @aleksv: OK, so you basically want the same filter types and input parameters as for the Cookbook, just with fewer artefacts at high frequencies, right? But if you used some optimization method, how would you do this in real-time? Or would you pre-compute and store some large set of coefficients for all possible specs?

Comment: Precomputation of coefficients is acceptable.

Comment: so alek, what exactly did you purchase?  you seem to be talking about a parametric EQ filter and Jazz (and you) seem to be discussing solving differential equations and even non-linear solutions.  that's a curiousity.  but if what you purchased lead's to a linear combination of $N$ states (recursively or not), it's a filter.  then the issue is what are the coefficients in that linear combination and there is no magic that will get you beyond the fact that the number of degrees of freedom are equal to the number of coefficients.  not even Andrew Simper can beat that fact.

Comment: @jazz, we've talked about this at the music dsp site.  if what you are modeling with your trapezoidal integration is non-linear, then you have a non-linear system.  if what you're modeling is an linear analog prototype, then your trapeziodal integration gets you to no different place than bilinear transform.  i proved that easily at the music dsp site.

Comment: @robert bristow-johnson, I've bought a formula code to calculate biquad peaking/bell filter. It somehow manages to preserve filter's bandwidth at any frequency. There's some inherent reduction of degrees of freedom in Cookbook code like a1=b1 which is absent in the code I've bought (licensed).

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, I don't know what you proved, but at best you did it for a first order trapezoidal integrator, which is trivial. It's higher order ODE solvers that make the game interesting, and they don't map linear ODEs by bilinear transform or in any other way to linear recursive digital filters.

Comment: alek, is what you have left are 5 coefficients?  it doesn't have to be the the basic Direct Form DF1 or DF2, it can be built from lattice or state-variable or whatever, but if the transfer function boils down to a 2nd-order rational function, then there are no more 5 coefficients and no more than 5 degrees of freedom.  now Knud Christensen has generalized the parametric to 5 degrees of freedom (he tosses in a "tilt" or "symmetry" parameter which rounds it out to 5).  but it still does not beat the problem of pushing the peak up against Nyquist.  it cannot.

Comment: robert bristow-johnson, it's doable nevertheless, in various ways (I have 2 different filter calc functions that do that, but they are licensed and I can't disclose them). Of course, these functions only assume a certain gain at Nyquist, they do not optimize the magnitude response derivative at Nyquist, so the form is not ideal, but it is sufficiently good and filter's bandwidth is almost constant across the spectrum, for any filter gain. I just need that for other types of filters. I can further "idealize" the bandwidth by introducing pre-correction formulas.

Comment: alek, your language is unpersuasive.  the math says that for a 2nd-order IIR filter, there are 5 independent coefficients.  no more, nor less (if you want complete generality for a 2nd-order IIR).  you have 5 degrees of freedom.  with the basic parametric EQ (like in the Cookbook), there are 3 independent parameters, $f_0$, $G_{dB}$, and something related to $Q$ or bandwidth.  and the gain at DC and Nyquist are 0 dB.  then add an overall gain coefficient that boosts or cuts **all** frequencies by some $G_0$, that's 4 degrees of freedom. then add the "tilt" or "symmetry" parameter and it's 5.

Comment: Of course, biquad has 5 degrees of freedom. But this is unrelated to my initial question.

Comment: @aleksv, your last statement only demonstrates lack of understanding.  is or is not your parametric EQ a 2nd-order IIR or not?

Comment: lack of understanding? of course it is 2nd order IIR filter I'm talking about.

Comment: then, what i have said throughout this entire question or thread stands.  it's simply what the math says.  if it's 2nd-order (so what Andrew, errr, Jazz says: *"In order to effectively compensate the aliasing and warping artefacts for discrete filters you have to use very high orders"* does not apply, because you're limited to 2nd-order), then the **whole** thing is about figuring out what the 5 coefficients are.

Comment: Yes, of course, the original question IS about finding the 5 coefficients (for each filter type).

Comment: okay, Alek.  solved problem.  been so for 11 years.  i hope you're paying your licensing fees to tc electronic, because they own it.

Comment: What are you talking about? So, Orfanidis also has to pay to tc electronic? Or is his solution somehow different? I can't quite understand what kind of "solution" you are talking about. Formulas can't be licensed, but code can. I licensed code and it has nothing to do with tc electronic in much the same way Orfanidis code is original.

Comment: no, Orfanidis precedes Christensen by another about decade.  and his solution is not as general.  in fact, the Orfanidis solution is precisely a special case of the Christensen generalized solution, at least if you tweek the $Q$ just right (i think Orfanidis may have used my compensation for the bilinear transform scrunching bandwidth, that might change the meaning of $Q$ just a little).

Comment: @aleksv Hi there, you mentioned you bought a formula code, I wonder would you kindly let me know where did you buy it as I really want to get one to solve my problem. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @jiandingzhe Sorry, the guy I've bought it from is no longer associated with audio DSP and probably won't sell the code.

Answer (score 6):

here is a quick look at how the 5 degrees of freedom for the parametric EQ can be viewed.  it's my take on what Knud Christensen of tc electronic came up with about a decade ago at [an AES convention](http://www.aes.org/e-lib/browse.cfm?elib=12429) and [this patent](http://www.google.com/patents/WO2004054099A1).

so, forget about the Cookbook (and the issues of Q and bandwidth therein) and consider (in the s-plane) the parametric EQ as the sum of a bandpass filter (with a $Q$ value) in parallel with a wire:

$$ H(s) = (G_\text{boost} - 1)\frac{\frac{1}{Q}\frac{s}{\omega_0}}{\left(\frac{s}{\omega_0}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{Q}\frac{s}{\omega_0} + 1} + 1 $$

$G_\text{boost} = 10^{\frac{dB}{20}}$ is the gain of the peak (or valley, if $dB<0$).  the gain at DC and at Nyquist is 0 dB. that's a 2nd-order IIR and there are 3 independent parameters. 2 more to go.  so we next add an overall gain parameter:

$$ H(s) = G_0 \left((G_\text{boost} - 1)\frac{\frac{1}{Q}\frac{s}{\omega_0}}{\left(\frac{s}{\omega_0}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{Q}\frac{s}{\omega_0} + 1} + 1 \right) $$

that's 4 knobs to twist.  one more knob to add (without raising the filter order) and we will be done with adding more independent parameters.

so what Knud does here is replace that "wire" (that trailing "$1$" in the transfer function) with a prototype shelving filter that **must** have the same poles, the same $Q$ and $\omega_0$ as the BPF, so that the denominator is the same.  the transfer function of that shelf is:

$$ H_\text{shelf}(s) = \frac{R\left(\frac{s}{\omega_0}\right)^2 + \frac{\sqrt{R}}{Q}\frac{s}{\omega_0} + 1}{\left(\frac{s}{\omega_0}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{Q}\frac{s}{\omega_0} + 1} $$

where $R \triangleq 10^{\frac{tilt}{20}}$ and $tilt$ is the gain differential of the shelf in dB.  this is what offsets the gain at Nyquist to be different than the gain at DC.  After bilinear transformation, Nyquist gets boosted by $tilt$ dB and the gain at DC remains unchanged.  Like the $dB$ boost parameter, the $tilt$ parameter can be either positive or negative.  $G_0 \cdot R$ is the linear gain at Nyquist.

put that all together and you get:

$$ \begin{align}
H(s) & = G_0 \left((G_\text{boost} - 1)\frac{\frac{1}{Q}\frac{s}{\omega_0}}{\left(\frac{s}{\omega_0}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{Q}\frac{s}{\omega_0} + 1} + H_\text{shelf}(s) \right) \\
 & = G_0 \left((G_\text{boost} - 1)\frac{\frac{1}{Q}\frac{s}{\omega_0}}{\left(\frac{s}{\omega_0}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{Q}\frac{s}{\omega_0} + 1} + \frac{R\left(\frac{s}{\omega_0}\right)^2 + \frac{\sqrt{R}}{Q}\frac{s}{\omega_0} + 1}{\left(\frac{s}{\omega_0}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{Q}\frac{s}{\omega_0} + 1} \right) \\
& = G_0 \frac{R\left(\frac{s}{\omega_0}\right)^2 + (G_\text{boost}+\sqrt{R}-1)\frac{1}{Q}\frac{s}{\omega_0} + 1}{\left(\frac{s}{\omega_0}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{Q}\frac{s}{\omega_0} + 1}  \\
\end{align}$$

no matter how you look at that, this has 5 degrees of freedom and those 5 biquad coefficients are **fully** defined from these 5 parameters.  doesn't matter if you map from $s$ to $z$ using the blinear transform or the trapezoidal rule (effectively the same thing) or any other method that does *not* change the order of the filter.  you may have to fudge the definition of $Q$ or bandwidth, you may have to compensate $\omega_0$ and/or $Q$ for frequency warping effects (like you get with the blinear transform), but if you paid big bucks for something that gets you a 2nd-order IIR filter, it doesn't matter if you implement it with any Direct Form or transposed Direct Form or Lattice or Normalized Ladder or Hal Chamberlin's State-Variable or Andrew Simpson's modeling of **linear** analog with trapezoidal integration, eventually you get to 5 coefficients and they can be mapped to these 5 independent parameters.  **it's all the same.**  whether or not you paid money for a license or not.  the math is stronger than any claims made by whomever you are licensing from.

Just FYI, i solved where the true peak or valley frequency is when there **is** a $tilt$ that is not zero.  the frequency where the peak or valley has been nudged over by the tilt is:

$$ \omega_\text{peak} \ = \ \omega_0 \ 
\sqrt{ \frac{Q^2 \left(R - \frac{1}{R}\right)}{G_\text{boost}^2 - R + 2 Q^2 (R - 1)} + \\ \sqrt{\frac{G_\text{boost}^2 - \frac{1}{R} + 2 Q^2 \left(\frac{1}{R} - 1\right)}{G_\text{boost}^2 - R + 2 Q^2 (R - 1)} + \frac{Q^4 \left(R - \frac{1}{R}\right)^2}{\left(G_\text{boost}^2 - R + 2 Q^2 (R - 1)\right)^2} } } $$

you can see that when $tilt = 0$, then $R=1$ and consequently $\omega_\text{peak} = \omega_0$.   the peak gain $G_\text{boost}$ might also have to be adjusted a little and that has yet to be worked out.  a good first guess would be $G_\text{boost} \leftarrow \frac{G_\text{boost}}{\sqrt{R}}$ or maybe $G_\text{boost} \leftarrow G_\text{boost}-(\sqrt{R}-1)$.

Comment: I cannot quite understand what you are trying to prove? 2nd order IIR filter has 5 degrees of freedom by definition. How your mapping of parameters to biquad coefficients helps to answer the original question?

Comment: so, once it became clear that *"of course it is 2nd order IIR filter I'm talking about"*, so that increasing the filter order *"to effectively compensate the aliasing and warping artefacts for discrete filters [using] very high orders"* is not in the cards, then, as best as i can tell from what you said, is that you paid money to license IP from someone to define those 5 coefficients.  and all i am trying to say is that this is a ***fully*** solved problem.  whether you paid for it or not.

Comment: The peaking filter calc code I have also uses 5 parameters: gain at DC, left edge freq and gain, peak freq and gain. I think it's important to specify edge freq to maintain a stable bandwidth.

Comment: It may be a solved problem, but where I can find a solution? Be it paid or not?

Comment: okay, now take a look at the [Orfanidis paper](http://www.ece.rutgers.edu/~orfanidi/ece521/peq.pdf), but use the math symbols above.  this is as good as you can do, because you only have those 5 knobs to twist.  you need to figure out what $G_0$ and $A$ are.  $\frac{G_0}{A}$ is the DC gain (maybe you want that to be 0 dB or $\frac{G_0}{A} = 1$, i dunno).  $A \ G_0$ is the gain at $\omega=\infty$, but, using bilinear transform, **that's** the gain at Nyquist.  so you have to figure out what you **want** the gain at Nyquist to be.  Sophocles has a suggestion.  dunno if i agree with it.

Comment: I have peaking filter calc code already. Orfanidis code is flawed (if doubt try it).

Comment: just to let you guys know, i cannot respond to this for another day or two.  bye, for now.

Comment: you will have trouble showing that the Orfanidis solution (the "code" was written by someone else, i am sure) is "flawed" for what it was presented as.  i have used it years ago and had no problem if i didn't push it too close to the edge.  there **is** an issue of whether Orfanidis' restriction or setting of gain at the Nyquist frequency is the best idea, but if the resonant frequency gets pushed up to Nyquist, **no** 2nd-order filter will behave how you want it to behave (like the analog EQ filter).  that is because the frequency response **must** be symmetrical about the Nyquist frequency.

Comment: Orfanidis code is unusable for general audio equalization as it has "glitches" at certain frequencies where bandwidth is erratically expanded. Maybe in theory its fine.

Comment: By the way, the MATLAB code is presented in Orfanidis paper, check it out. It IS glitchy.

Comment: upon review of my code, i **did** find a glitch workaround if the $G_\text{boost} = 1$.  a problem of division by zero in the other math for the Orfanidis method.  so you have to make sure that $G_\text{boost} < 0.99999$ or $G_\text{boost} > 1.00001$.  otherwise, i see no issue.  in any case, because of the necessary reflection of the frequency response curve about Nyquist, you will have problems with *any* discrete-time filter.  normally we upsample it (say $f_\text{s}=96\text{ kHz}$) so that we need not worry about Nyquist.

Comment: I do that G workaround as well, but the glitch is not about it. To really be able to see a glitch you have to be able to move the filter around the frequency and gain range and see the real filter's magnitude response - at some points you'll see the glitch.

Comment: while i can modify my answer, i cannot modify my comments.  the "$A$" above should be replaced with "$\sqrt{R}$".

Answer (score 3):

Using optimization methods, we can get a digital filter's frequency response closer to the target analog filter.

In the following experiment, a 6-order bandpass filter is optimized using Adam, an optimization algorithm often used in machine learning. Frequencies above the passband are excluded from the cost function (assigned zero weight). The optimized filter's response becomes higher than target for frequencies very close to Nyquist, but that difference may be offset by the anti-aliasing filter of the signal source (ADC or sample rate converter).
[image]
[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as clr
from scipy import signal

import tensorflow as tf

# Number of sections
M = 3

# Sample rate
f_s = 24000

# Passband center frequency
f0 = 9000

# Number of frequencies to compute
N = 2048

section_colors = np.zeros([M, 3])
for k in range(M):
    section_colors[k] = clr.hsv_to_rgb([(k / (M - 1.0)) / 3.0, 0.5, 0.75])

# Get one of BP poles that maps to LP prototype pole.
def lp_to_bp(s, rbw, w0):
    return w0 * (s * rbw / 2 + 1j * np.sqrt(1.0 - np.power(s * rbw / 2, 2)))

# Frequency response

def freq_response(z, b, a):
    p = b[0]
    q = a[0]
    for k in range(1, len(b)):
        p += b[k] * np.power(z, -k)
    for k in range(1, len(a)):
        q += a[k] * np.power(z, -k)
    return p / q

# Absolute value in decibel

def abs_db(h):
    return 20 * np.log10(np.abs(h))

# Poles of analog low-pass prototype

none, S, none = signal.buttap(M)

# Band limits
c = np.power(2, 1 / 12.0)
f_l = f0 / c
f_u = f0 * c

# Analog frequencies in radians
w0 = 2 * np.pi * f0
w_l = 2 * np.pi * f_l
w_u = 2 * np.pi * f_u

# Relative bandwidth
rbw = (w_u - w_l) / w0

jw0 = 2j * np.pi * f0
z0 = np.exp(jw0 / f_s)

# 1. Analog filter parameters

bc, ac = signal.butter(M, [w_l, w_u], btype='bandpass', analog=True)
ww, H_a = signal.freqs(bc, ac, worN=N)
magnH_a = np.abs(H_a)
f = ww / (2 * np.pi)

omega_d = ww / f_s
z = np.exp(1j * ww / f_s)

# 2. Initial filter design

a = np.zeros([M, 3], dtype=np.double)
b = np.zeros([M, 3], dtype=np.double)
hd = np.zeros([M, N], dtype=np.complex)

# Pre-warp the frequencies

w_l_pw = 2 * f_s * np.tan(np.pi * f_l / f_s)
w_u_pw = 2 * f_s * np.tan(np.pi * f_u / f_s)
w_0_pw = np.sqrt(w_l_pw * w_u_pw)

rbw_pw = (w_u_pw - w_l_pw) / w_0_pw

poles_pw = lp_to_bp(S, rbw_pw, w_0_pw)

# Bilinear transform

T = 1.0 / f_s
poles_d = (1.0 + poles_pw * T / 2) / (1.0 - poles_pw * T / 2)

for k in range(M):
    p = poles_d[k]
    b[k], a[k] = signal.zpk2tf([-1, 1], [p, np.conj(p)], 1)

    g0 = freq_response(z0, b[k], a[k])
    g0 = np.abs(g0)
    b[k] /= g0
    none, hd[k] = signal.freqz(b[k], a[k], worN=omega_d)

plt.figure(2)
plt.title("Initial digital filter (bilinear)")

plt.axis([0, f_s / 2, -90, 10])

plt.plot(f, abs_db(H_a), label='Target response', color='gray', linewidth=0.5)

for k in range(M):
    label = "Section %d" % k
    plt.plot(f, abs_db(hd[k]), color=section_colors[k], alpha=0.5, label=label)

# Combined frequency response of initial digital filter

Hd = np.prod(hd, axis=0)
plt.plot(f, abs_db(Hd), 'k', label='Cascaded filter')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')

plt.figure(3)
plt.title("Initial filter - poles and zeros")
plt.axis([-3, 3, -2.25, 2.25])
unitcircle = plt.Circle((0, 0), 1, color='lightgray', fill=False)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.add_artist(unitcircle)

for k in range(M):
    zeros, poles, gain = signal.tf2zpk(b[k], a[k])
    plt.plot(np.real(poles), np.imag(poles), 'x', color=section_colors[k])
    plt.plot(np.real(zeros), np.imag(zeros), 'o', color='none', markeredgecolor=section_colors[k], alpha=0.5)

# Optimizing filter

tH_a = tf.constant(magnH_a, dtype=tf.float32)

# Assign weights

weight = np.zeros(N)
for i in range(N):
    # In the passband or below?
    if (f[i] <= f_u):
        weight[i] = 1.0

tWeight = tf.constant(weight, dtype=tf.float32)
tZ = tf.placeholder(tf.complex64, [1, N])

# Variables to be changed by optimizer
ta = tf.Variable(a)
tb = tf.Variable(b)
ai = a
bi = b

# TF requires matching types for multiplication;
# cast real coefficients to complex
cta = tf.cast(ta, tf.complex64)
ctb = tf.cast(tb, tf.complex64)

xb0 = tf.reshape(ctb[:, 0], [M, 1])
xb1 = tf.reshape(ctb[:, 1], [M, 1])
xb2 = tf.reshape(ctb[:, 2], [M, 1])

xa0 = tf.reshape(cta[:, 0], [M, 1])
xa1 = tf.reshape(cta[:, 1], [M, 1])
xa2 = tf.reshape(cta[:, 2], [M, 1])

# Numerator:   B = b₀z² + b₁z + b₂
tB = tf.matmul(xb0, tf.square(tZ)) + tf.matmul(xb1, tZ) + xb2

# Denominator: A = a₀z² + a₁z + a₂
tA = tf.matmul(xa0, tf.square(tZ)) + tf.matmul(xa1, tZ) + xa2

# Get combined frequency response
tH = tf.reduce_prod(tB / tA, axis=0)

iterations = 2000
learning_rate = 0.0005

# Cost function
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tWeight * tf.squared_difference(tf.abs(tH), tH_a))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

zz = np.reshape(z, [1, N])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for epoch in range(iterations):
        loss, j = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={tZ: zz})
        if (epoch % 100 == 0):
            print("  Cost: ", j)

    b, a = sess.run([tb, ta])

for k in range(M):
    none, hd[k] = signal.freqz(b[k], a[k], worN=omega_d)

plt.figure(4)
plt.title("Optimized digital filter")

plt.axis([0, f_s / 2, -90, 10])

# Draw the band limits
plt.axvline(f_l, color='black', linewidth=0.5, linestyle='--')
plt.axvline(f_u, color='black', linewidth=0.5, linestyle='--')

plt.plot(f, abs_db(H_a), label='Target response', color='gray', linewidth=0.5)

Hd = np.prod(hd, axis=0)
for k in range(M):
    label = "Section %d" % k
    plt.plot(f, abs_db(hd[k]), color=section_colors[k], alpha=0.5, label=label)

magnH_d = np.abs(Hd)
plt.plot(f, abs_db(Hd), 'k', label='Cascaded filter')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')

plt.figure(5)
plt.title("Optimized digital filter - Poles and Zeros")
plt.axis([-3, 3, -2.25, 2.25])
unitcircle = plt.Circle((0, 0), 1, color='lightgray', fill=False)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.add_artist(unitcircle)

for k in range(M):
    zeros, poles, gain = signal.tf2zpk(b[k], a[k])
    plt.plot(np.real(poles), np.imag(poles), 'x', color=section_colors[k])
    plt.plot(np.real(zeros), np.imag(zeros), 'o', color='none', markeredgecolor=section_colors[k], alpha=0.5)

plt.show()
```

Comment: "Frequencies above the passband are excluded from the cost function (assigned zero weight)" Isn't there a danger that the filter becomes a sort of high-pass filter? Frequencies above passband could have large gain with no penalty given by such a cost function.

Comment: OK, II thought a symbol regression method would produce a finalized equation...probably for most cases,not all. while real-time derivative-free? optimization is a bit slow

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo: For some frequencies, it drops to zero after passband, like the initial filter.

Comment: @aleksv: There is another closed form solution that has not been mentioned here - http://www.khabdha.org/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/optimizing-the-magnitude-response-of-mzt-filters-mzti-2007.pdf

Comment: With `tensorflow-gpu` 1.12.0 the optimization is not converging, rather diverging. `tensorflow` 1.12.0 works better but the optimization does not fully converge, because of the choice of the optimizer (Adam) and its learning rate, and possibly because of the way the cost function is formulated. I will award the bounty to this answer, because it shows a modern approach to optimization of coefficients: automatic differentiation. I would still like to see: more stable optimization and arranging obtained coefficients for real-time use (such as parameter sweeps).

Comment: Hi igorinov, I'm confused with your code that it seems `tZ` is just a placeholder that initialized to zero, and you use it directly and B = b₀z² + b₁z + b₂, A = a₀z² + a₁z + a₂ to calculate the frequency response. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ZRHan At that point, those operations are added to the graph without calculating anything yet.
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/intro_to_graphs
I should port that example to TensorFlow 2 and Keras...

Comment: @igorinov OK, thanks! I got it.

Answer (score 2):

@Jazz, one of the things we learned in electrical engineering is that **any** order of differential equation can be broken down to a set (or "system") of 1st-order diff eqs.  so if trapezoidal integration, with the same "time step" $\Delta t$ is being used *consistently* for all continuous-time integrals, for a $N$th-order linear ODE, you can bust that up into $N$ first-order differential equations.  then consider just one of those 1st-order diff eqs:

again, consider emulating a capacitor.  let the sampling period be $T=\frac{1}{f_\text{s}}$ be the same as the "$\Delta t$" used in the trapezoid rule.

$$ i(t) = C \frac{dv}{dt} $$

or

$$ v(t) = \frac{1}{C} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{t} i(u) \ du $$

in the s-domain it's

$$ V(s) = \frac{1}{s} \left( \frac{1}{C} I(s) \right) $$

so trapazoidal integration at discrete times is:

$$\begin{align}
v(nT)  & = \frac{1}{C} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{nT} i(u) \ du \\
& = \frac{1}{C} \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{n} \quad \int\limits_{kT-T}^{kT} i(u) \ du \\
& \approx \frac{1}{C} \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{n} \frac{T}{2} \left( i(kT-T) + i(kT) \right) \\
& = v((n-1)T) + \frac{1}{C} \frac{T}{2} \left( i((n-1)T) + i(nT) \right)  \\
\end{align}$$

or as discrete-time sample values

$$ v[n]  =  v[n-1] + \frac{T}{2C} (i[n] + i[n-1]) $$

applying the Z transform

$$ V(z)  =  z^{-1} V(z) \ + \ \frac{T}{2C} \left(I(z) + z^{-1} I(z) \right) $$

solving for $V$

$$   V(z) = \frac{T}{2} \frac{1 + z^{-1}}{1 - z^{-1}} \left( \frac{1}{C} I(z) \right) $$

looks like we're substituting

$$ \frac{1}{s} \leftarrow \frac{T}{2} \frac{1 + z^{-1}}{1 - z^{-1}} $$

or

$$ s \leftarrow \frac{2}{T} \frac{z-1}{z+1} $$

which is precisely what the bilinear *without* compensation for frequency warping does.

Comment: This is what is usually called "proof by example" and hardly general. It also only treats the case that I already said was trivial in the comments above. Again, I'm talking about higher order implicit solvers that don't give a simple discrete recursion. It's also hardly the right place for this discussion as your answer has nothing to do with the original question. If you move this to a new question regarding ODE integration I'm willing to contribute to it.

Comment: no, it's completely general for linear diff eqs.  you are ignoring the opening statement about we learned long ago in electrical engineering classes.  (both in numerical methods and in control theory, an $N$th-order differential equation can be broken down to $N$ first-order differential equations. and then i require consistency; that the **same** trapezoidal rule for integration is used throughout.)

Comment: I am fully aware of the transformation of higher order ODEs into systems of first order ODEs. And again, it is *not* what I'm talking about. This statement doesn't make your proof any more general, as you just assert that the bilinear mapping transcends to the entire class while only treating a simple single example. Still, I'm not saying that your result is wrong, I'm talking about different solvers. Higher order solvers are *not* solvers of higher order DEs.

Comment: sorry, Andrew.  that's a **fail**.  you truly do **not** understand if you're continuing to maintain that modeling the continuous-time behavior of the **linear** analog components using trapezoidal integration, with the step time $\Delta t$ being the same as the sampling period $T=\frac{1}{f_\text{s}}$, then that is the **very** **same** **thing** as using bilinear transform without compensation for frequency warping.  same thing and the proof is above.

Comment: Sorry Robert, I'm not Andrew. And your proof above is like the following. I have two maps A and B, and some x. Both A(x)=c and B(x)=c, therefore A = B. That's obviously wrong. Even if A and B are linear, it's still wrong. You're right that a first order trapezoidal solver on a linear system will generate a recursive discrete system, but that's where it ends. You keep ignoring my repeated statements about higher order (adaptive/implicit) integrators. So I see the fail very much on your side.

Comment: okay, Jazz, start with a linear ODE of order $N$ and break it up, using the standard method, into $N$ first simple first-order linear differential equations.  then Laplace transform all of those 1st-order diff eqs.  now, in the s-domain, you will **only** see powers of $s$ as in $s^{-1}$.  but you know that when you recombine the $N$ 1st-order ODEs into the original $N$th-order ODE you will get your higher powers back.  but *each* of those $s^{-1}$ factors will be converted to $\frac{T}{2}\frac{z+1}{z-1}$ because that's what trapezoidal integration does.  and what bilinear does.

Comment: Then why don't you add all those details to your answer and make it a proof that deserves the name?

Comment: naw, it's good enough the way it is.  what is clear, when you break up your $N$th-order diff. eq. into $N$ first-order diff eqs., then **every** occurrence of $s^{-1}$ is replaced by $\frac{T}{2}\frac{z+1}{z-1}$, and remain so as you recombine these to higher powers of $s$.  that is precisely the same as what bilinear transform **without** compensation for frequency warping does.

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with a design for the 10dB peaking EQ. I've chosen 20 filters with center frequencies between 500 Hz and 16 kHz (Fs = 48 kHz). The top plot below is the design according to RBJ's [Audio-EQ-Cookbook](https://www.w3.org/TR/audio-eq-cookbook/), which is good but which leads to bandwidth distortion when the center frequencies get closer to Nyquist. The bottom plot is the new design where the filters very closely match the analog prototype filters:
[image]

And this is how the new notch filters look like compared to the Cookbook (bandwidth = 4 octaves, highest $f_0=23$ kHz):
[image]

The following figure shows a lowpass filter design ($Q=2$, $f_0=16$ kHz, $F_s=48$ kHz). Note that the new design approximates the analog prototype and for this reason it does not perform as a conventional lowpass filter (it has no zero at Nyquist):

[image]

Comment: Matt, i might suggest plotting the "peakingEQ" for, say, a 10 dB boost with a fixed $BW$, say 1 octave, and for a variety of peak frequencies, going up to close to Nyquist.  even though the Cookbook does a first-order compensation on $BW$ by multiplying by $\frac{\omega_0 T}{\sin(\omega_0 T)}$, it still cannot change the fact that the frequency response **must** be continuous and have continuous derivatives **and** it must be symmetrical about Nyquist.  even if you bump up the gain at Nyquist as does Orfanidis.  that, in and of itself, is the source of this warped frequency response.

Comment: i think he's expecting to see a digital filter, with a sample rate as low as 44.1 kHz, **match** the analog filter, even if the resonant frequency is just below Nyquist.  [this is something i had been worrying about 2 decades ago](http://www.musicdsp.org/files/EQ-Coefficients.pdf) and all i could think of doing easily is simply to compensate for the scrunching of bandwidth that bilinear transform does.  then Orfanidis changed one assumption (that the gain at Nyquist is 0 dB), and that helped a little more.  but the thing that really helps, is simply to bump up the sample rate.

Comment: Thanks for an attempt. The first Cookbook plot is what I want, but as Robert also noted, with the gain at Nyquist being non-zero. It will be also beneficial to draw the responses on the logarithmic scale in the range e.g. 20 Hz to Nyquist. Audio EQs rarely use a linear frequency scale. And bandwidth is usually specified in octaves. Any biquads have no problems with center/corner frequency up to about 300 Hz, but going higher reveals the issue.

Comment: No, I mean 0 to 300 Hz, lower frequencies. Above 300 Hz up to Nyquist these Cookbook filter formulas produce progressively increasing filter shape distortion. Of course, the sample rate is 44100 or 48000 as usual.

Comment: You have to plot the graph on the log scale. It is bandwidth distortion on the **LOG** scale what bothers me. There's no distortion present in the lower frequencies when seen on the log scale. Peaking, low-pass, high-shelf, notch filters always have 0 dB (unity) gain at DC.

Comment: @MattL. , for peakingEQ, it's two parallel filters summed, one a BPF (with gain of $(G_\text{boost}-1)$) and the other a wire (gain of $1$).  at DC the gain should be 0 dB.  at $\omega=\infty$, if it were an analog peakingEQ filter, the gain should also be 0 dB.  but, using the bilinear transform, this $\infty$ frequency gets mapped to Nyquist.  so what both Orfanidis and Christensen do (and latter is more general), is they still use bilinear but design the analog gain at $\infty$ to be something other than the gain at DC.

Comment: @MattL, yes, it looks exactly what's needed (at least for peaking filter). I would "zoom in" into the area 500 Hz to Nyquist and increase the number of magnitude plots, to see more variation.

Comment: @aleksv: I've designed some peaking EQ filters that are pretty close to the analog prototype filters. Please check my edited answer.

Comment: @MattL, this is great (only maybe a small peak gain overshoot is visible). Is your design procedure streamlined? I mean, can it be represented in C code? This may be needed to build interpolation tables for use in real-time.

Comment: @aleksv: This is just a proof of concept, the gain overshoot can of course be corrected very easily. The design method is probably best suited for offline pre-computation of coefficients. Anyway, I'm not planning on disclosing the method because it is a novel approach as far as I know. If you're interested in sets of coefficients, you can contact me (see my profile).

Comment: @aleksv: I added a plot showing the new notch filters in comparison with the Cookbook design.

Comment: I would also test your algorithm with some higher bandwidth value like 4 octaves.

Comment: @aleksv: I changed the notch filter example to a bandwidth of 4 octaves.

Comment: Looks good. What about drawing a little more curves up to 0.98 of Nyquist, not up to just 16kHz? Also as far as I can see, Notch's bandwidth in the lower frequencies is a bit imprecise, but I guess it's toleratable deviation.

Comment: @aleksv: Hey, this is fun ... I'm not sure if this is useful, but it can be done. Have a look. I guess by now it should be clear that the method actually works and produces results that are very different from methods based on the bilinear transform.

Comment: Can you also design low-, high-pass, high-shelf and band-pass filters?

Comment: @aleksv: Yes, the method works regardless of the filter type. For lowpass and bandpass filters it is a matter of taste what one likes, because approximating the analog filter might not be the best choice in these cases, because an analog lowpass filter with a low Q factor might have hardly any attenuation at Nyquist, so its digital counterpart is actually no lowpass filter at all. Here it's important to define what the desired response actually is, but I have ideas about that.

Comment: Well, since the goal is to have a constant bandwidth, it does not matter if low-pass becomes something else at Nyquist. Cookbook's prototypes are quite good. The Q factor is usually equated to the Gain - this way it becomes easy to manipulate the filter. E.g. set Gain to -3.01dB (0.707 linear) for a "standard" low- or high-pass filter.

Comment: @aleksv: OK, if the digital filter is supposed to approximate the analog prototype in all cases, then the design goal is at least very clear. Check out the new figure in my answer above.

Comment: hey Matt, this is interesting. so it's a LPF with a reasonably high Q (to get a bump), and since the bump height is directly related to $Q$ (in the s-domain, the peak is at $\omega_0\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{2Q^2}}$ and the peak height (assuming the DC gain is 0 dB) is $\frac{Q}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{4Q^2}}}$) we know that the bilinear transform will not change the peak height, so to get the different peak "sharpness" (looks like the Cookbook got it too sharp), you need to do a different mapping of $Q$. the Cookbook leaves $Q$ unchanged, but it **does** modify the mapping from $BW$ to $Q$ a little.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: There are two reasons for differences between the Cookbook design and the prototype lowpass filter: one is that the Cookbook gets too high a Q value for large $f_0$ (due to the bilinear transform), and the other one is the constraint that a Cookbook lowpass has both its zeros at Nyquist.

Comment: beg to differ, Matt, at least on semantics. the Cookbook's use of bilinear transform is quite vanilla-flavored use with the standard compensation for the "principal frequency" (in the LPF case, it's the resonant frequency, $\omega_0$) with **one** more twist, and that is a teeny bit of compensation for scrunching the bandwidth. but $Q$ remains uncompensated. however, the relationship between $Q$ and bandwidth **is** tweaked a little.  so the height of the bump must be the same (as it is with bilinear), but the location (relative to $\omega_0$) and width of the bump **is** adjusted.

Comment: and you're right about the two zeroes at Nyquist, which are mapped from $\infty$ to $\pi$ by the bilinear transform.  but that Knud Christensen thing **does** provide a degree of freedom to adjust that thing.  so your design **should** be a special case of the Christensen design (that has 5 degrees of freedom), where $G_\text{shelf}$, $G_0$, and $Q$ (and maybe the other two parameters) are adjusted by some mapping that your secret sauce knows about.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: OK, I know that there's some bandwidth compensation in the Cookbook formulas, but still, you can't help getting squeezed responses if you move towards Nyquist, that's the curse of BLT. And as for Christensen, I only read what you wrote in your answer because I don't have access to that paper, but if there are 5 degrees of freedom then, well, *any* biquad can be called a special case of that design.

Comment: precisely.  it's just that for some biquads (like a LPF with gain at Nyquist going to $-\infty$ dB) some of those parameters will also go to some version of $\infty$.  my curiosity is that your biquad filter should be able to be *inverse* bilinear-transform mapped back to the s-domain and **that** should be expressible with the bottom equation i have in that answer regarding Christensen's solution.  lemme know an email address and i'll send a copy, but i think my synopsis is more succinct.  that bottom s-domain equation has 5 independent parameters and should fit *any* 2nd-order $H(s)$.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: It would be great if you sent a copy! Please find my address via http://mattsdsp.blogspot.nl/ ('About Me').

Comment: @MattL. , are you publishing your solution somewhere?  (or is it something that you sell?)  i would like to try to come up with expressions for 5 parameters in what i posted here in terms of your solution.  i can see that you're keeping the peak frequency compensated and adjusting $Q$ so that the second derivative is also fixed, after frequency warping.  but either way, i see this as a 5 knob problem.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Haven't sold or published it yet. I don't have an analytic solution, I have an optimization method where I compute a discrete-time approximation of the analog prototype.

Comment: oh, okay.  not closed-form.  with the $\frac{\omega_0}{\sin(\omega_0)}$ bandwidth adjustment (which is accurate for thin bandwidths) in th cookbook, i was expecting to get the 2nd derivative well matched around the peak.  and given a "$tilt$" parameter, i can see how i would compensate the resonant frequency so that the peak remains unchanged, but i am still not certain what to set the "$tilt$" to be.  there is the "Orfanidis setting", but it should be set higher than that, and your optimized plots show that.

Comment: @MattL. did you get a copy of the Christenson paper?  i thought i got it to you, but i don't remember.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Yes, I got it, thanks.

Comment: @MattL. Hi there, your "new design" looks amazing! Would you kindly let me know about your new design? I really want to do it too, thank you in advance!