# What type of filter is that?

Tags: filters, discrete-signals, z-transform

I have a transfer function in z-plane with two poles and two zeros. I plotted the function with matlab

```matlab
k = 0.15;
z = [0.8 -1]';
p = [(0.51+1i*0.68) (0.51-1i*0.68)]';
[b,a] = zp2tf(z,p,k);
```

[image]

What type of filter is that? The closer I can think of is bandpass. But it has a really non -smooth peak so bandwidth would be zero? And also the magnitude remains negative which I don't know how to interpet.

Comment: I'd also say this is a bandpass. I don't understand your point about the peak being non-smooth? There's a range that you can define as a bandwidth of your filter, and I'd say under any reasonable definition this is a bandpass filter, and it's bandwidth is non-zero. What definition of bandwidth do you use to arrive at the claim that this has zero bandwidth?

Comment: @tonythgestark. A magnitude value can never be negative. A magnitude sample can small or large in value, but it is always positive.

Comment: You're reading the magnitude _in decibels_.  Negative dB just means the magnitude is less than one.  Also, it appears that your software is clipping the higher than unity gain -- there should be a sharp peak in the picture; it's not showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a 2nd order IIR biquadratic filter, consisting of a 2nd order resonator with additional zeros on the real axis at $z=0.8$, and $z=-1$. which is a bandpass filter.

I think the confusion is with the magnitude given in dB. dB is 20Log10(mag) and in that if the magnitude was a quantity between 0 and 1 it would be a negative dB quantity. As examples, the magnitude 0.707 is $20Log_{10}(0.707)= -3$ dB. Similarly the magnitude 1 is 0 dB, and the magnitude 0.001 is -60 dB.

Note that if we had the poles alone (with the two zeros at the origin), this would be a "2nd Order Resonator" with the response as given in the plot below showing the same transfer function (I adjusted the gain to be closer to 0 dB at resonance). Comparing this to the OP's plot, we see the impact of moving the zeros in the OP's transfer function to not be trivially at the origin. The one that is right on the unit circle at $z=-1$, corresponding to the frequency response at Nyquist, pulls the magnitude down toward 0 as the frequency approaches Nyquist, as a large negative dB quantity (exactly 0 at $f_s/2$). The zero near $z=1$, corresponding to the frequency response at DC, lowers the magnitude response at this point. Since this zero is not exactly on the unit circle, it only serves to reduce the response, but not significantly. We also see how the zero modifies the phase response. Please refer to [this post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/53148/why-do-we-put-poles-close-to-the-zeros-in-notch-filter/53149#53149) to visualize the relationship between the poles and zeros on the z plane and the frequency response.

[image: 2nd order resonator]

For more fun stuff with 2nd order resonators, see this great blog post by @RichardLyons [dsprelated.com/showarticle/183.php](http://dsprelated.com/showarticle/183.php) and this post [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/54006/computation-of-parameter-filter-to-match-a-given-frequency-response/54008#54008).

Comment: every bandpass filter has a bandwidth , here how do we compute that? 
I have seen the "classic" bandpass filter that has a constant top that it's length is considered the bandwith , but here i have a really narrow top around w = 0.3π , and I am not sure

Comment: It’s typically either the -3 dB points or -6 dB points when the top is normalized to 0 dB. That is also the case for “classic” filters where the top appears to be flat. (Perfect flatness is not theoretically possible but the ripple it droop can be made to be very small- there is a “maximally flat” filter but even that has a slope in thr passband)