# Calculating the filter coefficients for 2nd order bandpass and bandstop Butterworth filter

Tags: filters, filter-design, digital-filters, bandpass, butterworth

I want to calculate the filter coefficients for both bandpass and bandstop filter for 2nd order Butterworth filter, like

```py
  def low_pass_coeff(N: int, cutoff: int, samp_rate: int) -> tuple:
    '''
    N - order of the filter
    cutoff - cutoff frequency (in HZ)
    samp_rate - sampling rate of the signal
    '''

    norm_freq = cutoff / samp_rate

    ita = 1.0 / math.tan(numpy.pi * norm_freq)
    q = math.sqrt(2.0)
    b = numpy.ones(N+1)
    a = numpy.ones(N+1)
    b[0] = 1.0 / (1.0 + q * ita + ita * ita)
    b[1] = 2 * b[0]
    b[2] = b[0]
    a[1] = 2.0 * (ita * ita - 1.0) * b[0]
    a[2] = - (1.0 - q * ita + ita * ita) * b[0]
    return b, a
```

The above code is to calculate the filter coefficients for the 2nd order lowpass Butterworth filter, now I want the formula to compute the filter coefficients for the bandpass and bandstop filter...

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: An $N$th order bandpass or bandstop filter is mapped from a lowpass or highpass filter of order $\frac{N}{2}$.  That means a 2nd-order BPF comes from a 1st-order LPF.  For a 1st-order filter, the property *"Butterworth"* really has no meaning.  They are all Butterworth.

Comment: I might suggest googling "Audio EQ Cookbook" for a quick reference regarding coefficients of 2nd-order IIR filters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, also I have another doubt, do we have to calculate the zpk first and then the ba values, I found scipy signal library which performs in such a way. But I'm expecting to find the coefficients from a method similar to the above, like calculating the b and a values as above, but not with lowpass and highpass coefficients, directly the bp and bs filter coefficients... @robertbristow-johnson

Comment: The cookbook has complete recipes for a variety of filters.  It takes you all the way to the filter coefficients.

Comment: Thank you so much, for your answer.... and also for the book :)

Comment: yer welcome.....

Comment: I'm new to this dsp domain, so how can we obtain the Q parameter in your formula, and also, for bandpass filters, scipy libraries return coefficients of length 5 for 2nd order filters, while I can only see 3 values on that book....@robertbristow-johnson

Comment: You are astute to notice that with a 2nd-order IIR filter (biquad) there are 5 degrees of freedom because there are 5 coefficients.  So there are 5 independent parameters and when in the cookbook, only 3 parameters are specified, that means two other parameters are assumed fixed.  Those two parameters (for the peaking EQ) are [fixing the gains at DC and at Nyquist to both be zero dB](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2395981_The_Equivalence_of_Various_Methods_of_Computing_Biquad_Coefficients_for_Audio_Parametric_Equalizers).

Comment: If you want to control 5 independent parameters, then add the overall gain of the filter (which affects all 3 numerator coefficients) and this [spectral *tilt* parameter which is the difference between the gain at Nyquist and the gain at DC.](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/19225/audio-eq-cookbook-without-frequency-warping/19253#19253)  Then you have five independent controls and that's all you get with a 2nd-order IIR (or "biquad").

Comment: Thank you for your clarification.....